# Why does "Cannot return a void result" happen when Calendar is used a certain way?

Tags: java

Why does `getCal()` work but `getCal2()` doesn't? In Eclipse, I get an error saying "Cannot return a void result"

```
public Calendar getCal(long milliseconds) {
    Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
    c.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
    return c;
}

public Calendar getCal2(long milliseconds) {
    return Calendar.getInstance().setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because the method return type is `void`.

Here is the signature of that method

```
public void setTimeInMillis(long millis)
```

Take another `Calendar` and set time to it and return that `Calendar` instead.

```
Calendar anotherCalader= Calendar.getInstance();
 anotherCalader.setTimeInMillis(timeInMillies);
 return anotherCalader;
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html#setTimeInMillis(long)

Answer (score 1):

Because the method `setTimeInMillis(milliseconds)` in the [Calendar class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) returns void (nothing).

What you can do, if you want a Calendar returned, is:

```
public Calendar getCal2(long milliseconds)
{
    Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
    cal.setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
    return cal;
}
```

Or you can create a method that returns void:

```
public void getCal2(long milliseconds)
{
    Calendar.getInstance().setTimeInMillis(milliseconds);
}
```

If a method returns void, that means that you cannot set any variable to the value that method returns. `a_variable = someMethodThatReturnsVoid();` will give a compile time error since the method does not return anything.